# Returning a single row in a strongly typed DataSet in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dataadapter

I have a Strongly typed Dataset TableAdapter in C#, how do I get a single row from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var table = tableAdapter.GetData();
var resultRow = table.Rows[0];
```

EDIT: Strongly-typed datasets create a property for each column in the table, so to get the Id, this should work:

```
int id = resultRow.Id
```

You can also get fields by name:

```
int id = (int)resultRow["id"];
```

Comment: how can i get for example only the ID value from this row

Comment: var table = tableAdapter.GetData();
var resultRow = table.Rows[0];


i get the field name with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
myTableAdapter[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       var ta = new AddressTableAdapter();

       var ret = ta.GetDataBy(Convert.ToInt32(ASPxTextBox1.Text));
       var rw = ret.Rows[0];

       var city = (string)rw["City"];


       ASPxTextBox2.Text = city.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an additional parameterized query (i.e. 'WHERE ID = @id') and call that instead of the default GetData method:

```
var table = tableAdapter.GetDataById(123); 
var resultRow = table.Rows.First;
```